# MongoDb .NET - ObjectId serialization

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, api

I'm using my .net6.0 api,
this model:

```
public class Tournament
{
    public List<ObjectId> FriendsId { get; set; }
```

is serialized as:

> {"FriendsId":[{"timestamp":1654717093,"machine":540378,"pid":-19594,"increment":6387934,"creationTime":"2022-06-08T19:38:13Z"},...

but I want to have a string representation like this:

> {"FriendsId":[{"62a0f94f185b87a1a88c2354"},...

what is the right way to obtain this result?
my wish is to have a string rapresentation in json, keeping a list of objectid in the mongo entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the model like this adding the following attribute:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public List<string> Friends { get; set; } = new  List<string>();
```